# Sagepay simulator and tokenised cards

Tags: magento, opayo

I am setting up a dev site that uses SagePays simulator account and need to test tokenised cards.  Does the SagePay simulator support card tokenisaion?

Comment: I think not, you need a TEST or LIVE account to test tokenisation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SagePay don't allow tokenisation on simulator accounts but as Pablo said the SagePay test accounts are fine.  Managed to get access to a test account and all works fine now.